# DB Transaction following a safe path

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a DB Transaction following a safe path. So I'd like to do something using "do catch" statement, I'm wondering something like that:

```
    do {
        try? db.endTransaction()
        }catch{                //THIS WHOLE CODE CRASHES
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            db.rollbackTransaction()
        }
```

However, something is going wrong using this syntaxe. What am I doing wrong? Is this the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a `do` block, you should remove the `?` on `try` because the whole point of `do` is to catch errors that are thrown by things called with `try`. Once you do that, if your `endTransaction()` throws an exception, it should be caught by your `catch` block.